# SVN write through proxy out off sync

Tags: unix, svn, proxy, centos

Today ore svn mirrror got out off sync. The setup is as the headline describes. We have setup a mirror that does only read actions and write actions are committed to the master SVN server.

So on the mirror we have in the /etc/http/conf.d/mirror.conf file. this has 2 locations created. The private branch that redirects all writes to the master "SVNMasterURI" and a second  Where the sync from master is send to.

And yes, all hook scrip are executable. So the problem is : Some in 6 mounts the mirror would got out off sync because the locking mechanism was in please. So normally We would do a

```
svn propdel --revprop -r0 svn:sync-lock http://mirror/svn-proxy-sync
svnsync sync http://mirror/svn-proxyn-sync file:///home/master/svn/private
```

But now doing a svnsync sync http://mirror/svn-proxyn-sync file:///home/master/svn/private we get an error messages like :

```
 svnsync: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-                       revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
 svnsync: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
 svnsync: Error setting property 'sync-lock': 
 Can't find a temporary directory: Internal error
```

here are the config file:

master SVN

```
 <Location /svn/master >
  DAV svn
  SVNListParentPath Off
  SVNPath /home/master/svn/private
  #SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "BLA BLA"
  AuthUserFile /home/master/svn/etc/htpasswd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/master/svn/etc/private.access
  Require valid-user
 </Location>
```

Mirror write through proxy

```
 <Location /svn/mirror >
   DAV svn
   SVNListParentPath Off
   SVNPath /home/mirror/svn/private
   SVNMasterURI http://svnmaster/svn/master
   #SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "BLA BLA BAL"
   AuthUserFile /home/mirror/svn/etc/htpasswd
   AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/mirror/svn/etc/private.access
   Require valid-user
 </Location>

<Location /svn-proxy-sync >
   DAV svn
   SVNListParentPath Off
   SVNPath /home/mirror/svn/private
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

Also when we tried to do a

```
svnsync init commando we are getting the same output
```

So PLEASE HELP!!!!

Comment: Well I found the error. It seems that the /var/log/http was around 17GB off logging. When removing those log the sync did ok.

Comment: Well its a bit strange thou, because there is platy off disk space....Had to change the logrote.d/http